# Arranging layout, I am using bootstrap 4.1.3

Tags: html, css

I have this layout, here in this image :

[image]

I want the boxes to be listed dynamically. Every of the columns are inside the row. 
Is it possible to do it with css?

Here is a simple snippet to the above image.

```
<!-- https://codepen.io/umanga/pen/dQRVGX --!>
```

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? Seems like a prime example for [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS code:

```
.col-md-3 { order: 2; } 
.col-md-3:nth-child(2),
.col-md-3:nth-child(3) { order: 0; } 
.col-md-6 { order: 1; }
```

Comment: This would work with static page but when the developer loops col-md-3, won't it be a problem there?

Comment: Yes, Maybe my code should not work with developer loops. In that case, you should try this CSS code with your structure:
.col-md-3 {
  order: 2;
}
.col-md-3:nth-child(2),
.col-md-3:nth-child(3) {
  order: 0;
}
.col-md-6 {
  order: 1;
}

Comment: Right Exactly, Its the order i was looking. I totally forgot about that. Thanks a lot bro